# How long will program stay in memory without power?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, memory

Let's say we program an arduino uno or nano and then stop using it for a while. How long can we expect the program to last on the arduino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than 20 years, and probably more than 100 years.

That's the guaranteed minimum:

> Data retention: 20 years at 85°C/100 years at 25°C<sup>(1)</sup>
>
> <sub>(1)  Reliability Qualification results show that the projected data retention failure rate is much less than 1 PPM over
>   20 years at 85°C or 100 years at 25°C.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Practically forever. Rather make sure the contacts don't become too rusty.
( 83.7 % of Arduino problems are mechanical and contact issues :) )

Will your grandchildren still have a legacy USB cable and be interested in that thing and your c++ coding skills then?

Answer (score 0):

upto 20 years at 85°C and upto 100 years at 25°C